# Could not extract ResultSet, Column not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have a entity like

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "ebooking")
    public class EBooking {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "bookId")
        private String bookId;
```

And I implemented repository llike

```
public interface EBookingRepository extends JpaRepository<EBooking, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<EBooking> {

    @Query("select book from EBooking book where book.bookId = :id")
    EBooking getByBookId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

When I try to run this method i have exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column ebooking0_.book_id does not exist
  Position: 8
```

Why `ebooking0_.book_id`? There is only `ebooking` table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ebooking0_` is an alias for `ebooking` table generated by Hibernate. You can check that if you turn on SQL logging.

Error does indicate that you don't have column `book_id` in table `ebooking`.